# Why does my program keep returning the input prompt?

Tags: c, linux, clang, prompt

This code compiles perfectly, but when I run it, on the second ´scanf´ it will always return the prompt, like its expecting an infinite amount of values. I'm using Clang on Linux. I really need your help as I have an exam this Friday.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

int fatorial(int n){
    int f=1, t;
    for(t=n;t>1;t--){
        f=f*t;
    }
    return f;
}

float sen(float x, float tol){
    float res=0, aux=0;
    int n=0;
    for(n=1;res-aux!=tol||aux-res!=tol; n++){
        res=aux;
        res=res+(pow(-1,n+1))*((pow(x,2*n-1))/fatorial(2*n-1));
    }
    return res;
}
int main(){
    float yo, tol, res;
    printf("What's the value of x? ");
    scanf(" %f", &yo);
    printf("What's the tolerance? ");
    scanf(" %f", &tol);
    res=sen(yo, tol);
    printf("The sin of %.2f is %f.\n", yo, res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "always return the prompt"? It's not clear what you mean by that.

Comment: sure ^-^ basically it asks "What's the tolerance?" and i input a number, then press enter and it keeps asking for a number in a new line.

Comment: What input values are you using? Perhaps you could show a screenshot of what you see? There are no loops in the input part of your code, so it's unclear how it could possibly be asking more than once.

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/INZzQWD.png) does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your linked screenshot, your program is not *asking* for more input. It's calculating an answer. In Linux, you can still type things into the terminal while a program is running, which is what you are doing.

You can use `top` or other CPU monitor to see that your process is using 100% CPU. The problem is that your algorithm in `sen()` is running an infinite loop and never reaching its target tolerance value.

Comment: -_- really?! that?! its always the small things...basically i put the aux after the res, when it was supposed to be aux=res...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
float sen(float x, float tol){
    float res=0, aux=tol+1;
    int n;
    for(n=0;fabsf(res-aux)>tol; n++){
        aux=res;
        res=res+pow(-1, n)*pow(x, 2*n+1)/fatorial(2*n+1);
    }
    return res;
}
```